Force Java JTable cells to paint entire row as one
For a file browser app I'm working on, I need to get an entire JTable row to repaint as a single entity. Is there a way to do this?
The specific behavior I'm seeking is to highlight items under the cursor when the user drags an item over the JTable. Using a custom renderer, I'm able to cause an individual cell to highlight. But the drag gesture only causes the cell under the cursor to change. I need the entire row to redraw at the same time.

Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

It sounds like you want a specific painting behavior during a drag-and-drop operation.  Is that correct?

Yes VGR. When I'm dragging, I want the whole row repainted, not just the cell the cursor's hovering over.

Are you using a TransferHandler, or are you using the java.awt.dnd package directly?

Apologies for the delay VGR. Yes, using a TranferHandler.

It appears JTable already highlights the row under a drag, with no special cell renderers needed.  Perhaps your renderer is not behaving properly.  Edit your question and show the code of your renderer, and also show how you’re making use of that renderer.
